# Changing time zones for JS clock display

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to display the current time on a site I'm building.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Could someone tell me what code to add in order change the time to a different time zone? I'd also love the time to display 12 hour increments rather than 24.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you look at https://momentjs.com/ they have very easy to use methods that would solve this issue for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the time zone by converting the time to UTC and adding the needed number of hours

```
var utc = today.getTime() + (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var newDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * -2));
```

As for converting to 12 hour format

```
var h = newDate.getHours() % 12;
```

```js
function startTime(id, offset) {
    var today = new Date();
    var utc = today.getTime() + (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var newDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * -2));
    var h = newDate.getHours() % 12;
    var m = newDate.getMinutes();
    var s = newDate.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body onload="startTime();">

<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**

As mentioned by @BrockLee in a comment - as it is it will, indeed, show 12'o clock as 0. If this is not desired, you could change the line that sets the hours to, for example,

```
var h = (newDate.getHours() % 12 == 0) ? 12 : newDate.getHours() % 12;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I also added this code to include AM/PM. `h = h > 12 ? h + ":" + m +'PM' : h + ":" + m +'AM';`

Comment: if you do var h = newDate.getHours() % 12; and it was 12:00, wouldn't it show as 0:00?

Comment: @BrockLee yup, you're right, I added an edit noting that

Comment: I just came back here because the clock was displaying 0. Thanks so much for adding this. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In that example, you could use `today.toLocaleTimeString()` instead to show it in the preferred format of current user's locale.

Also, [MDN's documentation on Date/Time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) related functionality in JavaScript will probably be much more helpful.